# How to use awslog driver in to get the logs from the docker container?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

I have a docker container running in EC2. The logs in the container are written at /var/log. How do I use the awslog driver to get these logs from the container and store it?

Answer (score 4):

Works fine for me.

1. Create a IAM user in AWS console with the following policy:

> ```
>    "Version" "2012-10-17" 
>     "Statement" 
>         "Action" 
>             "logs:CreateLogStream" 
>             "logs:PutLogEvents" 
>             "Effect" "Allow" 
>             "Resource"
> ```

2. Add AWS credentials to docker host system, add a "aws-credentials.conf"

> ```
> mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/
> touch /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/aws-credentials.conf
> ```

3. Insert into aws-credentials.conf

> ```
>  [Service]
>     Environment"AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=<aws_access_key_id>" 
>     Environment"AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=<aws_secret_access_key>"
> ```

4. Reboot docker Host and create an Cloudwatch Logstream
5. Add this to your docker-compose (v2) to start logging

   > ```
   > logging 
   >      driver "awslogs" 
   >      options 
   >         awslogs-region "eu-west-1" 
   >         awslogs-group "my-group" 
   >         awslogs-stream "my-stream"
   > ```

Tested on Ubuntu 15.10

Comment: Thanks. I was able to get it working. I used a similar solution

Comment: this work form me:
Environment="AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=<api_key>" "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=<access_key>"

Comment: I get error: `error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to initialize logging driver: failed to create Cloudwatch log stream: operation error CloudWatch Logs: CreateLogStream, failed to sign request: failed to retrieve credentials: failed to refresh cached credentials, no EC2 IMDS role found, operation error ec2imds: GetMetadata, canceled, context deadline exceeded`

Comment: I am getting the same error as @kittu